# Probability and independence of variables

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, density-function

Given two continuous variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ in range the range $0$ to $1$, we have a probability density function $p(x_1,x_2|y)$ defined as:
$$p(x_1,x_2|y=1) = \begin{cases}4 &\text{if } x_1\leq 0.5 \text{ and } x_2 \leq 0.5\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$$p(x_1,x_2|y=2) = \begin{cases}2 &\text{if } x_1 + x_2 \leq 1\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$$p(y=1) = p(y=2) = 0.5$$

The question is: are $x_1$ and $x_2$ independent when its given that $y=1$ and when $y=2$? 
According to the solution discussed in class, the answer is yes when $y=1$ and no when $y=2$. But I do not understand how?

Also, this is a question of classification. The $y=1, y=2$ are the two classes. I also need to find the probability of misclassification when the correct class is $y=2$.

Comment: Characteristic for independence is that PDF of PMF $f(x_1,x_2)$ can be written as a product $f(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1)h(x_2)$. That can be done in the case $y=1$ and not in case $y=2$.

Comment: What if we forget about $x$ and $y$ and instead define variables $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ whose joint density function is $p(Z_1,Z_2) = 2$ if $Z_1\geq0,$ $Z_2\geq0,$ and $Z_1+Z_2\leq1.$ Can you figure out why $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are not independent? Did drhab's comment help? Or do you still not see how we can show it?